# Azure Data Explorer error when creating cluster: subscription '' is not registered

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

While working on this official tutorial [Create an Azure Data Explorer cluster and database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-cluster-database-portal), I am getting the following error when creating a Cluster. **Question**: What I may be missing and how the issue can be resolved?

**Remarks**:

1. I'm using `Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription - MPN`
2. My online search shows similar error [here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=64G4X_OCLsew5wLciYy4Ag&q=azure%20error%20subscription%20%27%27%20is%20not%20registered.&oq=azure%20error%20subscription%20%27%27%20is%20not%20registered.&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQHjIGCAAQCBAeOgQIABBHSgUICBIBMVDlggNY5YIDYOmPA2gAcAZ4AIABP4gBP5IBATGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwizpL7j0ZLtAhVH2FkKHdwEAycQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) but the context seems different since those error messages are related to `The subscription not registered to use namespace`. Not sure if there is a relevance to my error.

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"SubscriptionNotRegistered","message":"The subscription 'a86d7e9f-210d-48e8-8f5e-528015d1c998' is not registered."}]}

**Using the link provided in the error, I got the following**:

[image]

**When I click on the 'write cluster resource' link from the above screen**:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you did not register the Kusto resource provider as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types)

However, once you create a new cluster for the first time on a given subscription and it fails because the provider is not registered, Kusto tries to register it for you. So if you try again it should just work, if not please follow the process in the link.

Comment: Your observation of its failure when creating cluster for the first time was correct. After I tried it again, it worked fine. Thank you for not only providing a solution but explaining the reason behind the failure - this was important for me (you deserve my upvote). I would suggest that your suggestion be included in the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-cluster-database-portal), as well since most people working on this feature first time would almost definitely encounter this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion nam, I submitted a doc fix, it will take a couple of days to propagate and published. Thanks again!